# Separate string using RegExp

Tags: php, regex

I have a string coming in that has productID's and their quantity separated by comma

ex. 2334(3),2335(15)

how could I turn this into an array easier than using explode substr explode? I'm terrible with RegExp, but I think you can lazy capture the variables?

like:
$a[2334] = 3

Comment: regex is not any easier, as you would perform the regex and still need to manipulate the data afterwards to be in the array format you described.

Comment: In fact, I would even say that `Substring()` could be faster. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917747/regex-to-match-a-string-after-colon/3917749#3917749

Comment: I would agree with you Blue, but at the same time, I'm not assured that every product number would be the exact same length. Now you could do a reverse sub-string but that wouldn't constitute that the quantity remained a certain number of characters. I'm just trying to let it be flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)\((\d+)\)/', '2334(3),2335(15)', $matches)) {
    $output = array_combine ( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
    print_r($output);   
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [2334] => 3
    [2335] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sProducts = '2334(3),2335(15)';
$products = array();

$regex = '/(\d+)\((\d+\))/';

preg_match_all($regex, $sProducts, $matches);
$products = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($products);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [2334] => 3) [2335] => 15) )
```

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/k9g-057

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$input = '2334(3),2335(15)';

//split your data into more manageable chunks    
$raw_arr = explode(',', $input);

$processed_arr = array();
foreach( $raw_arr as $item ) {
  $matches = array();
  // simple regexes are less likely to go off the rails
  preg_match('/(\d+)\((\d+)\)/', $item, $matches);
  if( !empty($matches) ) {
    $processed_arr[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
  } else {
    // don't ignore the possibility of error
    echo "could not process $item\n";
  }
}
```