# c# remove string before character in a paragraph

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to remove string before colon `:`. I need all string after the colon.

**Input:**

```
"Country: USA <br> 
 Address Line1: Texas  <br>  
 Address Line2:  Austin <br>"
```

**Output:**

```
USA <br>
Texas  <br> 
Austin <br>
```

**Code:**

```
string address = "Country: USA <br> Address Line1: Texas <br> Address Line2: Austin <br>";

address = address.Substring(address.IndexOf(':') + 1);// This removes only one string before colon ,rest remains same
string[] output = address.Split(':');// This also includes the left part before colon
```

**Note:** This is not a duplicate question because other questions are based on single character , but here we deal with multiple occurrences of colon and `<br>` in a string.

Any help would be great.

Comment: you can break into lines with <br> adn then do what you're doing.'

Comment: Split it on `<br>`, then split each of *those* strings on the colon.  Then recombine using `<br>` as the separator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match a string after colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917747/regex-to-match-a-string-after-colon)

Comment: @Scath FYI, this is not a duplicate question, Kindly read my Note and the code. I have used the code of the duplicate link but it dint solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give a non-regex alternative, you can split by `<br>` (*did you mean `<br/>`?*) and then do your substring approach:

```
string[] output = 
    address
    .Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(row => row.Substring(row.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim() + " <br>")
    .ToArray();
```

Or you can do your semicolon split approach:

```
string[] output = 
    address
    .Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(row => row.Split(':').Last().Trim() + " <br>")
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you would need to split on two delimiters. But I ran your code and it gave:
Country <br>
Address Line1 <br>
Address Line2 <br>
 <br>

Comment: Yeah, I selected `[0]` after the inner split.  Changed it to `.Last()`.  Thanks.

Comment: I was expecting a `Linq` based answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you like linq and you follow the "church of the one line" this should work:

```
 address
    .Split(new string[] { ":", "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Trim()
    .Where((ignore,index) => (index % 2) == 0)
    .Select((item) => item+"<br>")
    .ToList();
```